# XCUITesting continuously crashing my application

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode-ui-testing

My application is crashing with following stack -

### [image: Crash]

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0 0x0722dd39 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1 0x0722da0e in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2 0x1782b083 in -[UITableViewCellAccessibility _accessibilityChildren] ()
#3 0x1782ccd0 in -[UITableViewCellAccessibility accessibilityElementCount] ()
#4 0x1794d241 in -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityHasOrderedChildren] ()
#5 0x1795a3d2 in -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityFrameForSorting] ()
#6 0x1795a4ba in -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityCompareGeometry:] ()
#7 0x07201532 in __36-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:]_block_invoke ()
#8 0x0720150a in __56-[NSArray sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:]_block_invoke ()
#9 0x071e7ddd in __CFSimpleMergeSort ()
#10 0x071e7e13 in __CFSimpleMergeSort ()
#11 0x071e7e2c in __CFSimpleMergeSort ()
#12 0x071e7cf3 in CFSortIndexes ()
#13 0x071f364a in -[NSArray sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:] ()
#14 0x07201454 in -[NSArray sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator:] ()
#15 0x072013f0 in -[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:] ()
#16 0x178362df in -[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityUserTestingChildren] ()
#17 0x1796ec58 in -[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingChildrenCount] ()
#18 0x17953483 in -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:] ()
#19 0x1796f559 in -[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotDescendantsWithAttributes:maxDepth:maxChildren:maxArrayCount:] ()
#20 0x17970778 in -[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotWithOptions:] ()
#21 0x17951a60 in -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:forParameter:] ()
#22 0x1793b59d in _copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback ()
#23 0x179c9538 in _AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue ()
#24 0x179c319a in _XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue ()
#25 0x179d24b3 in mshMIGPerform ()
#26 0x07201125 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#27 0x07201090 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#28 0x071f6546 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#29 0x071f5866 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#30 0x071f567b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#31 0x0806a664 in GSEventRunModal ()
#32 0x0806a4a1 in GSEventRun ()
#33 0x04d52cc1 in UIApplicationMain ()
#34 0x0002dc3e in main at 
#35 0x07bbea21 in start ()
```

---

With following message in console -
-[UITableTextAccessibilityElement retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x24f4db30

My application works fine when it is used without UI testing.
I tried to record the UITest using the UI recorded but still I face same crash.
I then wrote the UI test manualy but still get same crash in my application.

The stack does not shows provide any information through which I can debug my application.

Any help on this is appreciated.

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu6vnqoe32xu93e/TestProject.zip?dl=0) - Use following steps to reproduce the crash in sample project.

- In above sample project try to run the test testExample in TestProjectUITests.m.
- Or Alternatively-Try to use UI Recorder to record the UI test with following steps

  1. Type some text in To field
  2. Tap on summary field
  3. Type some text on on cc field
  4. Tap on bcc field
  5. Types some text on bcc field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by apple in XCode 7.2 beta 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to provide some helpful suggestion if you could post some code or sample app where this issue is cropping up.You could also run zombie instrument to verify the memory stack with every release/retain on the object if a zombie is encountered. 
However, the console error clearly points to a dodgy UITableView or UITableViewCell in your code.You can probably hunt them down in your app navigation path exercised during test.
I suspect there is retaining property,

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *accessibleView
```

in swift , properties are strong(retain count) by default,

```
var accessibleView: UiView?
```

defined while setting up UIView subclass where you might be using UIAccessibilityContainer methods to expose UI elements as accessible elements.It seems property is release in dealloc() or the view is popped from stack.
Things will be more clear if you could post some code.

Comment: Sample project added https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu6vnqoe32xu93e/TestProject.zip?dl=0